# Changing variables for the same Movie Clip object for each level

Tags: actionscript-3, function, movieclip

Hey guys so I'm having a little trouble trying to figure out how to do this. I have a Movie Clip Object named mcGoal_1 and in its class i have it tween Up and Down the stage vertically using TweenLite. On Level_1 it starts on the bottom, but when level_2 is initiated i want it to start at the top but cant figure out how to change the values each level to accomplish this. Here is the code i use for it to start at the bottom:

```
private function init():void 
    {
        TweenMax.to(this, 4, { y:40, repeat: -1, yoyo:true, ease:Power0.easeInOut } );
        TweenLite.from(this, 2, {autoAlpha:0});       
    }
```

Then in my Engine Class i have it added to the stage using this piece of code:

```
   mcGoal_1 = new goal_1();
stage.addChild(mcGoal_1);
mcGoal_1.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) + 350;
mcGoal_1.y = (stage.stageHeight) - 35;
```

So everything works just fine but what i want to accomplish is changing the position of the mcGoal_1 at the beginning of each new level. So in level_2 i want my mcGoal_1 position to start at the top instead of the bottom here is the code for it to start at the Top:

mcGoal_1 Class:

```
private function init():void 
    {

        TweenMax.to(this, 2.8, { y:445, repeat: -1, yoyo:true, ease:Power0.easeInOut } );
        TweenLite.from(this, 2, {delay:2,autoAlpha:0}); 

    }
```

Then in the Engine Class:

```
mcGoal_1 = new goal_1();
        mcGoal_1.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) + 350;
        mcGoal_1.y = (stage.stageHeight) - 445;
```

So now it starts at the top.

How i am doing this right now is im creating multiple mcGoals. I have a new goal each level so right now i have a bout 10 goal MovieClips. But i was thinking it would be much easier if i could just change the value of mcGoal_1 every new level instead of creating a whole new movie clip just to start at the top instead of the bottom. I was thinking that maybe i need to just create 2 separate functions 1 function is for when it starts at the top of the stage and the other for the bottom of the stage. So i would take the Tweens from my mcGoal_1 Class out and add them to the Engine Class so i can change the values correct?

Something like this maybe in the Engine Class:

```
Private Function startAtTop():void
    {
  mcGoal_1 = new goal_1();
        stage.addChild(mcGoal_1);
        mcGoal_1.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) + 350;
        mcGoal_1.y = (stage.stageHeight) - 35;

  TweenMax.to(mcGoal_1, 4, { y:40, repeat: -1, yoyo:true, ease:Power0.easeInOut } );

    }




Private Function startAtBottom():void
{
  mcGoal_1 = new goal_1();
        mcGoal_1.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) + 350;
        mcGoal_1.y = (stage.stageHeight) - 445;

 TweenMax.to(mcGoal_1, 2.8, { y:445, repeat: -1, yoyo:true, ease:Power0.easeInOut } );

}
```

Then i would just call whichever function in each new level. This doestn quite work though because thhe function is called every frame per second and that causes TweenLite to not work correctly.

Please any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one class as far as I can see. You have a init method. You should provide the init method with the information its needs to set itself up correctly.

Goal:

```
private function init(startPosition:Point, endPosition:Point):void 
{
    this.x = startPosition.x;
    this.y = startPosition.y;
    TweenMax.to(this, 4, { y:endPosition.y, repeat: -1, yoyo:true, ease:Power0.easeInOut } );
    //you could use endPosition.x for a tween here as well
    TweenLite.from(this, 2, {autoAlpha:0});       
}
```

LevelConfig Class:

```
package{
import flash.geom.Point;

public class LevelConfig {

    private var _startPosition:Point;
    private var _endPosition:Point;

    //add more properties

    public function LevelConfig(startPosition:Point, endPosition:Point) {
        this._startPosition = startPosition;
        this._endPosition = endPosition;
    }

    public function get endPosition():Point {
        return _endPosition;
    }

    public function set endPosition(value:Point):void {
        _endPosition = value;
    }
}
}
```

Engine:

```
function initLevels():void
{
    levels = new Vector.<LevelConfig>();
    levels.push(new LevelConfig(new Point((stage.stageWidth / 2) + 350,(stage.stageHeight) - 445),new Point((stage.stageWidth / 2) + 350,445));

    levels.push(new LevelConfig(new Point((stage.stageWidth / 2) + 350, 445),new Point((stage.stageWidth / 2) + 350,(stage.stageHeight) - 445));

    //add more levels
}

var levels:Vector.<LevelConfig>;
initLevels();

function startLevel(level:int):void
{
    var mcGoal:Goal = new Goal();
    var config:LevelConfig = levels[level];

    mcGoal.init(config.startPoint,config.endPoint);
}
```

then you can just start a level with the call `startLevel(levelIndex)`
You would normally load the level configuration from an external source. XML or JSON
Be aware that the levelIndex starts with 0! So your level 1 is 0. You could also add level name, description and what ever to this model.

Comment: Interesting. So you assigning point variables. But im still a bit confused with the code.I cant quite see how it will change its starting position for each new level tht starts up.

Comment: see my additions. You have to construct some kind of configuration for your level. It is not practical to lay out all possible positions of one item with methods.